# Use realm with promise in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, promise, kotlin, realm

I've tried to use the realm library with promise in Android (Kotlin) but when the "resolve" method is executed, the list of the object returned is invalid.

In the next example, i created a "findCountries" method, this method find the countries in async mode (Actually i use the promise to sync in my realm database if apply, and then make a query from my realm db)

```
fun findCountries(query: String? = null): Promise<Any?,Any?>{
val deferred = deferred<Any?,Any?>()
var result : List<TopupCountry> = ArrayList()
Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransactionAsync(Realm.Transaction { instance->
    result = instance.where(TopupCountry::class.java).findAll()
    deferred.resolve(result)
}, Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess {
    Log.i(ActTpListCountry.LOG_TAG,result.toString())
})
return deferred.promise}
```

in the example above, if the realm class has data, and you get the value of the "result" param before calling the "resolve" method, it will return the data perfectly. But, when you catch the result inside of resolve callback, it says that every object is invalid.

[See an error image example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNphB.png)

Any suggest?

Comment: You have 3 problems: 1.) you don't close the Realm instance, ever 2.) you are trying to open an asynchronous write transaction for reading instead of just, well, using `findAllAsync()` and 3.) you are trying to access a RealmResults from a different thread than you retrieved it from so it gives you illegal state exception

Comment: Reading [the official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) and [referring to official example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/ad88afe897a9fe6ca6f00fb04586e78f06b1b539/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java#L59-É66) might help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the problem is related with the observation #3, i will check the official example and i'll let you know, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice by @EpicPandaForce and i found an alternative solution:

```
 /**
     * Method to find the countries
     */
    fun findCountries(query: String? = null, event: RealmEvent? = null){
        val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        val result = realm.where(TopupCountry::class.java).findAllAsync()
        result.addChangeListener(OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener { realmResult, changeSet ->
            event?.onFindResult(realmResult)
            realm.close()
        })
    }
```

In this case, im using the async function from realm and apply the change listener method. Now, i going to use interface instead of promise

Comment: That is better but now you are going to run into https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#addChangeListener-io.realm.RealmChangeListener-

Comment: Aka "sometimes" the results won't be called